# Unable to install tkinter using python3.8

Tags: python-3.x

I tried using the commands below and these are the errors I got:

(1) `sudo apt-get install python3-tk`:

Error : Package python3-tk is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

(2) `python3.8 -m pip install tkinter`:

Error : Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tkinter (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tkinter

(3) `python3.8 -m pip install python3-tk`:

Error : Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python3-tk (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for python3-tk

Comment: You cannot install tkinter with pip.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows put this on your CMD:

```
pip install tkinter
```

If it doesn't work, try:

```
pip install tk
```

For Mac or Linux:

```
apt-get install python-tk
```

Make sure you have python and pip installed. You can check it in the following way:

For python:

```
python --version
```

For pip:

```
pip -V
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, i am using Ubuntu 18.04 version. I am unable to install for Python3.6 but not for python3.8.
Currently i am migrating to Python3.6.